# How can I insert 2 other value in scanf one time

Tags: c, scanf

I have an incorrect number in numB.

How can I insert 2 other value in scanf one time?
Or it can't do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a,b;
    int numA,numB;

    printf("A : ");
    scanf("%c%d",&a,&numA);

    printf("B : ");
    scanf("%c%d",&b,&numB);

    printf("\n\n%d %d",numA,numB);
 }
```

result

```
A : S 67
B : D 56


67 1684370524
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value read into `b` is the newline character (Enter key) that you pressed after typing in `67`.  Then reading `numB` fails because it tries to interpret `D` as `numB`.

If you had typed `S 67 D 56 <Enter>` (i.e. without the Enter in the middle) then you would get the right output.

To fix this, one way is to change your format string to `" %c%d"`. The space means that it will consume any whitespace before trying to read a character.

Answer (score 1):

You get a newline from after the first number in `b`, and then an undefined value in `numB`.  Use `" %c%d"` to avoid this problem; it skips white space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a, b;
    int numA, numB;

    printf("A : ");
    scanf(" %c%d", &a, &numA);

    printf("B : ");
    scanf(" %c%d", &b, &numB);

    printf("\n%d %d\n", numA, numB);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char a,b,e;
    int c,d;
    printf("A: ");
    scanf("%c %d",&a,&c);
    e=getchar();
    printf("B: ");
    scanf("%c %d",&b,&d);
    printf("%d %d",c,d);
}
```